# nVidia GeForce GT 630M problems

Tags: video, gpu

So, this is my video card, supposedly a decent one.

http://gpuboss.com/graphics-card/GeForce-GT-630M

I cannot however play YouTube videos on 1.25 speed smoothly. There are nVidia drivers installed as far as I know. Could there be anything else at play?

Comment: What do you mean you can't? Do videos stutter or not play at all?

Comment: Videos pretty much stutter. It's very annoying and impossible to follow. I have a smaller Toshiba notebook with specs a lot worse and it's doing the job fine.

Comment: What laptop model is this? Try updating Intel GPU and NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: Laptop: https://www.asus.com/my/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/A45VD/specifications/

Comment: try switching off hardware acceleration - that's not a particularly fast graphics card - see http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-resolve-problems-with-flash-on-youtube/

Comment: Turns out, I'm not even using flash on youTube, but HTML5 player instead. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score -2):

Yes this may be your internet speed you can check it at www.speedtest.net 
if its not over say 5 mbs you will have issues

Hope that helps 
Matt

Comment: This appears to be a comment.  I suggest you get yourself some reputation so you can comment on other people's questions.